# Difference between "inspect" and "interactive" command line flags in Python

Tags: python, command-line, interpreter

What is the difference between "inspect" and "interactive" flags?
The [sys.flags function](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.flags) prints both of them.

How can they both have "-i" flag according to the documentation of sys.flags?

How can I set them separately? If I use "python -i", both of them will be set
to 1.

#### Related:

- [tell whether python is in -i mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640389/tell-whether-python-is-in-i-mode/640405)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [pythonrun.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/pythonrun.c?view=markup) corresponding `Py_InspectFlag` and `Py_InteractiveFlag` are used as follows:

```c
int Py_InspectFlag; /* Needed to determine whether to exit at SystemError */
/* snip */
static void
handle_system_exit(void)
{
    PyObject *exception, *value, *tb;
    int exitcode = 0;

    if (Py_InspectFlag)
        /* Don't exit if -i flag was given. This flag is set to 0
         * when entering interactive mode for inspecting. */
        return;
    /* snip */
}
```

Python doesn't exit on `SystemExit` if "inspect" flag is true.

```c
int Py_InteractiveFlag; /* Needed by Py_FdIsInteractive() below */
/* snip */
/*
 * The file descriptor fd is considered ``interactive'' if either
 *   a) isatty(fd) is TRUE, or
 *   b) the -i flag was given, and the filename associated with
 *      the descriptor is NULL or "<stdin>" or "???".
 */
int
Py_FdIsInteractive(FILE *fp, const char *filename)
{
    if (isatty((int)fileno(fp)))
        return 1;
    if (!Py_InteractiveFlag)
        return 0;
    return (filename == NULL) ||
           (strcmp(filename, "<stdin>") == 0) ||
           (strcmp(filename, "???") == 0);
}
```

If "interactive" flag is false and current input is not associated with a terminal then python doesn't bother entering "interactive" mode (unbuffering stdout, printing version, showing prompt, etc).

`-i` option turns on both flags. "inspect" flag is also on if `PYTHONINSPECT` environment variable is not empty (see [main.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/main.c?view=markup)).

Basically it means if you set `PYTHONINSPECT` variable and run your module then python doesn't exit on SystemExit (e.g., at the end of the script) and shows you an interactive prompt instead of (allowing you to inspect your module state (thus "inspect" name for the flag)).

Answer (score 0):

`man python` says about the `-i` flag:

> When  a  script  is  passed  as  first
>   argument or the -c option is used,
>   enter interactive mode after executing
>   the script or the command.  It does
>   not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file. 
>   This can be useful to inspect global
>   variables or a stack trace when a
>   script raises an exception.

Hence `-i` allows **inspection** of a script in **interactive** mode. `-i` *implies* both of these things. <strike>You can be interactive without inspecting (namely by just calling `python`, without arguments), but not vice versa.</strike>

Comment: "You can be interactive without inspecting (namely by just calling python, without arguments)" -- It does not seem to be the case. If I start "python" and print "sys.flags", the "interactive" flag is false.

Comment: Interesting. Well, that would explain why they are both associated with the `-i` flag. Leaves us to wonder: why differentiate in the first place?