# Batch script for Python

Tags: python, batch-file

Good afternoon,

I have a py script that I need to automate via a batch file. Now, the batch I have created is as follows python"C:\Users\ShaneN\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\ShaneN\Desktop\PYGAM.py" but when I attempt to run it, the cmd screen flashes and closes before I can see what's happening. Also to note that it does not run the script.
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375173/how-to-stop-python-closing-immediately-when-executed-in-microsoft-windows This might answer your question

Answer (score 0):

run script in compiler of python because I think there is error in your code that causes cmd to close bec no return value or user input to make cmd. freeze

Comment: This is not correct. `cmd` will close even if the code runs successfully if there is no `PAUSE` at the end of the `.bat`.

Comment: and I don't say different from. that i said no user input to freze cmd so run at compiler to. see. run. time :)

Comment: "Because I think there is error in your code that causes cmd to close". ?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the first half is still wrong.

Comment: first have  "think" second half solution in two ways if error he will know if not he will pause

Answer (score 0):

The batch script closes once it's done. Once a script has no more code to run, the window closes. If you want to keep the window open, you can use the `pause` command.

You can try to run the script in `command prompt` and use **echo** and **pause** to help with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of some error in the code.
Try adding

```
input('Press enter to exit ')
```

on the last line

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it still flashes and closes...bizarre!