# Double click on python file only 1 blink and no execute

Tags: python

I double click on my python file, which simply prints Hello world but it only a black thing flashed and disappears. The terminal is not opened.
My other PC works fine.

I need to do it this way since the Task Scheduler show the same black thing flash when I run task on executing python script.

I spent 2 hours searching around for solution but nothing works.

My file is C:\temp.py and If I open cmd navigate to this file, it will be executed correctly ( cd C:\ ; then C:\temp.py )

I remove the 3.11 version to install 3.7 version and still not work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Hong

Comment: Can you check it from terminal? I mean open terminal and navigating there, then running the code with `python temp.py` to see what happens?

Comment: add an `input("Enter to continue")` at the start and again at the end ... when you double click it opens and runs and closes before you can see it is really the issue

Comment: If your python script "*simply prints Hello world*" then there is no reason for the terminal to _remain open_. The script probably ran correctly, printed out something, then immediately exited. The "black thing" that flashes is probably the terminal that just opens-and-closes really fast.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to stop Python closing immediately when executed in Microsoft Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12375173/2745495)

Comment: You are right. '''input("enter to cont") do make the terminal shows up. For my real code (verified running in 2 other PCs), after double click, the terminal opens and runs correctly. But in this PC it doesn't run. Yes, when I open terminal and run this real code in this trouble PC, it runs as expected.

Comment: When I put ```'''input("enter to cont")``` in my real code and double click, the terminal shows. after hit enter, terminal close immediately. I can run this real code in terminal as normal.

Comment: OK, I found it. somehow some package, like schedule, is not run in my terminal. I have to install them and now it runs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

If you add this line to the end of your code, the terminal should wait for your you to press the `enter` key before closing.