# My Python code works perfectly when I debug it in Visual Studio Code, but it closes as soon as I hit enter when I open it in the command prompt

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, crash

First of all I literally just now made an account here so I apologize if I'm posting this wrong or something. But anyway:

Basically what the title says. I'm making a text-based fake OS (weird I know, but bear with me) using Python. When I tested it in Visual Studio Code's debugger, everything worked perfectly. However, I wanted to test it in the same environment that my future users will, so I right-clicked the file in File Explorer and selected open with Python, which of course brought me to the command prompt.

All was going well until I hit enter, then text appeared on the screen for like a nanosecond and the command prompt window just closed.

I looked it up and many people are saying to add a text input, but mine has several already and it's still closing. And again, please note that it works fine in Visual Studio Code's debugger.

I don't think I should post all 400 lines of code, but I'll put the important parts of the code below:

```
import time
import getpass

#Start of Bootup:

def welcome_user():
    print("Welcome to rOS!")

def boot_up():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Booting up...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The system has successfully booted.")

#End of Bootup
    
#Start of Login:

def get_password():
    password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
    return password

def create_password():
    password = getpass.getpass("Create a password: ")
    return password

def save_password(password):
    with open("password.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(password)

def load_password():
    try:
        with open("password.txt", "r") as file:
            password = file.read().strip()
            return password
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    
#End of Login

def calculator():
    #My calculator code doesn't have anything to do with the problem so I'm not posting it now.
    pass

def antivirus():
    #Again, it's not necessary for this post; it's here as a placeholder.
    pass

def desktop():
    print("------------------------------")
    print("DESKTOP")
    while True:
        program = input("Enter a program name: ")
        #The programs are simulated fyi
        if program == "list":
            print("------------------------------")
            print("Antivirus")
            print("Calculator")
            print("------------------------------")
        elif program == "antivirus":
            antivirus()
        elif program == "calculator":
            calculator()
        else:
            print("Invalid program name. Please try again.")
            continue

#More of the login stuff:

def login():
    password = load_password()
    if password:
        while True:
            entered_password = get_password()
            if entered_password == password:
                print("Login successful!")
                desktop()
                break
            else:
                print("Incorrect password. Please try again.")
    else:
        password = create_password()
        save_password(password)
        print("Password created!")

def main():
    welcome_user()
    boot_up()
    time.sleep(1)
    login()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope that code isn't too long. My real code is much much longer.

But anyway, whenever I open the py file and hit "enter" after I've created a password in the program, text appears but it immediately exits out of command prompt. But it's fine in VS Code.

Comment: The thing is that in VScode the prompt stay open even after the code has finished, while if you run like you did outside the prompt is gonna close instantly t the end. If you open a prompt and run it from there it will not close or you can add a text input to the end, something like `press enter to exit the prompt` so that will pause the code up until you want to close it.

Comment: Is your "login" successful? Is the function `desktop()` executed (at least once)?

Comment: And yeah, you are never calling `desktop` in this example and also there is no way to exit the loop, so you should add an option for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Python closing immediately when executed in Microsoft Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375173/how-to-stop-python-closing-immediately-when-executed-in-microsoft-windows)

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in the comments if you want to run it just executing the code you should just add an `input` at the end that allows to stop the execution that will exit the prompt.

```
import time
import getpass

#Start of Bootup:

def welcome_user():
    print("Welcome to rOS!")

def boot_up():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Booting up...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The system has successfully booted.")

#End of Bootup
    
#Start of Login:

def get_password():
    password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
    return password

def create_password():
    password = getpass.getpass("Create a password: ")
    return password

def save_password(password):
    with open("password.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(password)

def load_password():
    try:
        with open("password.txt", "r") as file:
            password = file.read().strip()
            return password
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    
#End of Login

def calculator():
    #My calculator code doesn't have anything to do with the problem so I'm not posting it now.
    pass

def antivirus():
    #Again, it's not necessary for this post; it's here as a placeholder.
    pass

def desktop():
    print("------------------------------")
    print("DESKTOP")
    while True:
        program = input("Enter a program name: ")
        #The programs are simulated fyi
        if program == "exit":
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        elif program == "list":
            print("------------------------------")
            print("Antivirus")
            print("Calculator")
            print("to exit type 'exit'")
            print("------------------------------")
        elif program == "Antivirus":
            antivirus()
        elif program == "Calculator":
            calculator()
        else:
            print("Invalid program name. Please try again.")
            continue

#More of the login stuff:

def login():
    password = load_password()
    if password:
        while True:
            entered_password = get_password()
            if entered_password == password:
                print("Login successful!")
                desktop()
                break
            else:
                print("Incorrect password. Please try again.")
    else:
        password = create_password()
        save_password(password)
        print("Password created!")

def main():
    welcome_user()
    boot_up()
    time.sleep(1)
    login()
    input("Press enter to exit the prompt.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also added the `exit` program to go out of the loop and change the condition to enter the Antivirus and Calculator statements because if you put the Upper case letter in the `list` you should have in the condition. (I add a `pass` in the two function because without it is gonna throw an error)

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing a script in vscode, you should use the **`Run Python File`** option

[image]

If you are using the command to execute the script in a terminal, open a terminal in the directory where the script is located, and then use the `python name.py` command to execute the script