# Tell if Python is in interactive mode

Tags: python, interactive, python-2.5, python-2.x

In a Python script, is there any way to tell if the interpreter is in interactive mode? This would be useful so that, for instance, when you run an interactive Python session and import a module, slightly different code is executed (for example, logging is turned off).

I've looked at [tell whether python is in -i mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640389/tell-whether-python-is-in-i-mode) and tried the code there, however, that function only returns true if Python has been invoked with the -i flag and not when the command used to invoke interactive mode is `python` with no arguments.

What I mean is something like this:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    #do stuff
elif __pythonIsInteractive__:
    #do other stuff
else:
    exit()
```

Comment: Consider using the `logging` module for logging in libraries, so users can control it with a shared configuration.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`__main__.__file__` doesn't exist in the interactive interpreter:

```
import __main__ as main
print hasattr(main, '__file__')
```

This also goes for code run via `python -c`, but not `python -m`.

Comment: This is also the case in, for example, py2exe executables.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work inside an embedded shell. I.e. a shell started with IPython.embed()

Comment: `bool(getattr(sys, 'ps1', sys.flags.interactive))`, py2.6+

Comment: So far none of the solutions seems to be able to detect `PYTHONSTARTUP=script.py python3`. The expression `'readline' in sys.modules` can, as well as `python3 -i script.py` and `python3 -ic 'import script'` (tested with Python 3.8.2 on Ubuntu focal), but it's highly non-portable.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for `ptpython` interactive session started via `python -m ptpython`.

Answer (score 57):

I compared all the methods I found and made a table of results. The best one seems to be this:

```py
hasattr(sys, 'ps1')
```

[image]

If anyone has other scenarios that might differ, comment and I'll add it

Comment: Hey thank you for doing the hard work, would you be able to check Windows vs Linux vs Mac?

Comment: `hasattr(sys, 'ps1')` returns `False` in PyCharm 2022.1.4 (CE) console on Windows 11

Comment: I i forgot to mention that the interpreter is Python 3.10.6

Answer (score 29):

[`sys.ps1`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.ps1) and [`sys.ps2`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.ps2) are only defined in interactive mode.

Comment: @Keith seems to work fine for me in iPython 3.2.1 REPL using python 2.7.9

Comment: Agreed, I just checked in 4.0 and it works there as well. May have been an issue with older versions of IPython.

Comment: Seems to me that `sys.ps1` and `sys.ps2` are defined even when iPython is run *not* in interactive mode.

Answer (score 19):

Use [`sys.flags`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.flags):

```
if sys.flags.interactive:
    #interactive
else:
    #not interactive
```

Comment: This only checks for command line argument `python -i` and is not a test of being in the Python interactive mode by typing `python` alone.

Comment: `bool(getattr(sys, 'ps1', sys.flags.interactive))`

Answer (score 7):

From [TFM](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html): If no interface option is given, -i is implied, sys.argv[0] is an empty string ("") and the current directory will be added to the start of sys.path.

If the user invoked the interpreter with `python` and no arguments, as you mentioned, you could test this with `if sys.argv[0] == ''`. This also returns true if started with `python -i`, but according to the docs, they're functionally the same.

Comment: Uh oh. Direct violation of the Zen of Python, then :)

Comment: Heh... Though I think @echoback's version is the only obvious(ish) one. I didn't accept this simply because in C et al., it is theoretically possible that `argv[0]` is `NULL` or an empty string and I don't really feel like debugging any potential errors caused by that...

Comment: This may be problematic for other interpreters, however. For example, when using IPython, sys.argv = ['/usr/bin/ipython']

Answer (score 1):

The following works both with and without the -i switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
# Set the interpreter bool
try:
    if sys.ps1: interpreter = True
except AttributeError:
    interpreter = False
    if sys.flags.interactive: interpreter = True

# Use the interpreter bool
if interpreter: print 'We are in the Interpreter'
else: print 'We are running from the command line'
```

Comment: `if sys.ps1: interpreter = True` => `interpreter = sys.ps1` or `interpreter = bool(sys.ps1)`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu:  You might want to actually test your code before you post it. Even if it was valid Python it would throw an AttribeError exception when run from the command line.

Comment: Did I recommend removing the `try ... except` statement? I only recommended replacing an `if` with a plain assignment.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: You made no such recommendation.  Apparently you thought that the => communicated a whole lot more than it actually does.  Of course, once one understands what you meant to say rather than what you said, your solution is longer and more compute intensive, but whatever floats your boat I suppose.

Comment: My bad for being elliptic, but I fail to understand how 27 characters are longer than 30 or why is it more compute intensive when `if` also needs the boolean value of `sys.ps1`.

Comment: I mistook the last "or" as a Python statement rather than an English word, so as you say "my bad" on that.  Now that I see that, your first proposal will assign ">>> " to sys.ps1 thereby causing a cast every time you use it, and also introducing an inconsistency where the type of "interpreter" is different depending upon runtime mode.  On my system the pyc file for my solution is 3 bytes smaller than your second solution:  You can try it yourself to verify, obviously.

Comment: You're right about that inconsistency, that's why I also proposed a second variant. I have python-2.7.5-13.fc20.x86_64 and the corresponding **pyc** is indeed bigger with 5 bytes for the `bool` variant. But if I also change the `except` code to `interpreter = bool(sys.flags.interactive)`, the file is smaller with 27 bytes :-D

Comment: NECROMANCY!: `bool(getattr(sys, 'ps1', sys.flags.interactive))`

Answer (score -4):

Here's something that would work. Put the following code snippet in a file, and assign the path to that file to the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable.

```
__pythonIsInteractive__ = None
```

And then you can use

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    #do stuff
elif '__pythonIsInteractive__' in globals():
    #do other stuff
else:
    exit()
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file