# How to detect whether the user is in python shell or the python command prompt window

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a program, and I'm looking to be able to see if python can detect the user is in python command prompt window, and if they are, then do so and so.

I'm running python version 3.5.1

Here is what I am mean by the python command prompt window:

[image: Command Prompt Window]

Comment: What is "the 32-bit window"?

Comment: edited it to its proper name. mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking `sys.stdin.isatty()` may be what you need, especially in conjunction with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356420/223424).