# Is is possible for a python script to know whether it is run with the interactive option '-i'?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tell whether python is in -i mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640389/tell-whether-python-is-in-i-mode)
>   [Tell if python is in interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356399/tell-if-python-is-in-interactive-mode)

Is there a way to check whether a python script has been run with the interactive option -i?

e.g.

```
if interactive_mode:
    print 'I am in interactive mode!'
else:
    print 'I am in batch mode!'
```

Then call with

```
python hello_world.py
I am in batch mode!

python -i hello_world.py
>> I am in interactive mode!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
if sys.flags.interactive:
    print 'I am in interactive mode!'
else:
    print 'I am in batch mode!'
```